# VB.NET & SQL Server Determining Boolean Values Using CheckedListBox

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-2008, boolean, checklistbox

I have 1 table named `CivilStatus`

`CivilStatus` has these columns, all with `bit` data type:

- `Single (bit)`
- `Married (bit)`
- `Widow (bit)`
- `Separated (bit)`
- `Live-in (bit)`

Now, I created a project in VB.NET with a CheckedListBox in it named `clbCivilStatus`. Inside the CheckedListBox `items` property are the collection I listed above. This is the code I made to put values in my table using a stored procedure:

```
Dim single as Boolean
Dim married as Boolean
Dim widow as Boolean
Dim separated as Boolean
Dim livein as Boolean

single = IIf(clbCivilStatus.SelectedItem(0), 1, 0)
married = IIf(clbCivilStatus.SelectedItem(1), 1, 0)
widow = IIf(clbCivilStatus.SelectedItem(2), 1, 0)
separated = IIf(clbCivilStatus.SelectedItem(3), 1, 0)
livein = IIf(clbCivilStatus.SelectedItem(4), 1, 0)

 Dim strConn As String = "my sql connection"
            Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection

            sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)

            Using (sqlCon)

                Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand

                sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon

                sqlComm.CommandText = "Insert"
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Single", single)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Married", married)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Widow", widow)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Separated", separated)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("LiveIn", livein)

   sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

...but visual studio gives me this error:

InvalidCastException was unhandled

Conversion from type 'Char' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

I want Boolean values in my database, is there a way to do this using a CheckedListBox?

Comment: Single is a reserved keyword choose a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using the property `SelectedItem(x)`, but this is a reference to the x.th character in the string of the one and only one [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) element of your list.
It is not the value of the checkbox associated with the x item in your list.

To get the value of the checkbox you need to use [GetItemCheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemcheckstate(v=vs.110).aspx) and compare it with the enum CheckState.Checked

```
single = IIf(clbCivilStatus.GetItemCheckState(0) = CheckState.Checked, 1, 0)
married = IIf(clbCivilStatus.GetItemCheckState(1) = CheckState.Checked, 1, 0)
widow = IIf(clbCivilStatus.GetItemCheckState(2) = CheckState.Checked, 1, 0)
separated = IIf(clbCivilStatus.GetItemCheckState(3) = CheckState.Checked, 1, 0)
livein = IIf(clbCivilStatus.GetItemCheckState(4) = CheckState.Checked, 1, 0)
```